# Area 51 Questions per Day/Percentage Answered

Tags: support, questions

I have a question regarding the area 51 stats - do the questions per day and percentage answered include questions that are closed?  I'm trying to understand if the percentage answered represents all questions, or just those that are considered appropriate to be asked/answered.

Comment: I would expect it to be all questions, but hopefully a SE mod will provide us a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the stats do include closed questions. They do not include *deleted* questions however.